# calling a class inside another class function

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create an educational website using django so I have a `class` model and a `course` model. I have tried to use the `Many-to-one` `foreignkey` relationship but that doesn't work, I can create classes using `foreignkey` but that class is not being assigned to that course only. It appears in other courses as well. So how can I make this work? What should I change?

My models.py:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='class/class_videos',null=True,
validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['MOV','avi','mp4','webm','mkv'])])


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='class/instructor_pics', null=True)
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    instructor_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='class/instructor_pics', null=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='courses_joined', blank=True)
    classes = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Please add more details about how you are making the classes and what is your expected result.

Comment: I expect that if I create a class within a course that class should only be assigned to that specific course, i.e if I visit the course-detail-page I should be only seeing the classes assigned to that course.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the foreign key in the wrong model. If each class can only have one course, but a single course, can have multiple classes, you should place the ForeignKey in the class model instead of the course model. Your code would be like this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='class/instructor_pics', null=True)
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    instructor_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='class/instructor_pics', null=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='courses_joined', blank=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Class(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='class/class_videos',null=True,
validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['MOV','avi','mp4','webm','mkv'])])
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='classes')


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

And when you want to list the classes of a single course, you can use this code (you should use the `related_name` field in the source model like the way I have used in the class model):

```
course = Course.objects.filter(some_filter=some_value).first()
course.classes.first() # This will return the first class of the course
```